# Timeout with socket io

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nginx, socket.io

I have an application using socket.io with Node and Express. I'm also using AWS EC2 and Nginx.

I'm getting a timeout with socket io.
The error is:
GET https://vusgroup.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MnUHunS 504 (Gateway Time-out)

Express file:

```
var port = 8090;
host = 'https://18.237.109.96'
var app = express(host);
var webServer = http.createServer(app);

...

// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
var socketServer = socketIo.listen(webServer, {"log level":1});

//listen on port
webServer.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('listening on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Nginx file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.

                proxy_pass http://18.237.109.96:8090/;
        }
}

server {
        server_name vusgroup.com www.vusgroup.com; # managed by Certbot

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

... 

ssl stuff 

...

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.

                proxy_pass http://18.237.109.96:8090/;
        }

        location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_pass              http://18.237.109.96:3000;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_http_version      1.1;

                proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection              "Upgrade";

                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }


}
```

I've tried chaning the proxypass for socket.io to http://18.237.109.96:8090; but that gave me a 400 error.

Comment: Facing the same problem today, but I have it event on localhost when I serve my files via Webpack dev server. Haven't found any solutions ;(